# C scanf char array

Tags: c

my problem is that the printf does not get me any output. I'm totally confused. Any idea why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char var[50];
scanf_s("%s", var); // visual studio force me to use scanf_s
printf("In: %s\n", var); // the output is just 'In:'

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @mbratch Visual studio nonsense.

Comment: @mbratch - Mr Gates idea of `scanf`

Comment: Get NetBeans! It's free.

Comment: @FiddlingBits; For C, GCC is better.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How exactly did visual studio force you?

Comment: @haacks I'm assuming the OP prefers IDEs.  It is possible to configure NetBeans to use gcc and gdb for its compiler and debugger, respectively.

Comment: @mafso 1>c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c learning\c learning\blatt3.c(6): error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: By the way. I've found a solution to be able to use the standard scanf instead of scanf_s. Just add this line: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: Then _please_ give a buffer size (as in "%49s") -- `scanf` can't magically guess your buffer sizes ;)

Comment: scanf("%49s", var); does not work :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf_s` needs size too as argument;

```
scanf_s("%s", var, 50);
```

Comment: Why did they decide to put the size as the variable argument instead of a real one!? If they didn't OP wouldn't have this problem now.

Comment: @self I don't know think of Microsoft.  but  for the prevention, perhaps.

Comment: @self.; That's why its called Micro **soft** C!